# НЕКОЙ или НЕКОЕЙ

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Как писать: *некой* или *некоей*? (В предложении "Эта статья некой (некоей?)...")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Некой* или *некоей?*

Формы эти считаются **равноправными**.

См. [Лариса Рудь, Ирина Кудреватых, Василий Стариченок [**"Культура речи"**]](https://books.google.ru/books?id=iUWiDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA146&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%20%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6sXAlqLSAhVGJ5oKHQeuBswQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%20%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&f=false):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]